# How can I deal with my released app's crashes in main.m?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I used Bugly(a tool same as Crashlytics) to recored crashes in my app which had released.But sometimes there are some crashes in main.m as the report showed:[image: crash detail]

With these information I can't location problem in my code at all.I need to know which class and which method the problem occured so I can location this problem.

I wonder is there any way I can location problem more precise?And how do you deal with these crashes in your released app?

Wish you can share,thanks a lot.

Comment: It looks like the crash is happening as the application is being snapshotted (which happens when it's suspended or goes to background).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I find this is memory leak result.Use Xcode instrument check is a good way.